# %SYSFUNC() wrapped concatenation functions give an error while encountering parentheses

Tags: function, loops, macros, sas

I need to write a macro program to generate a list for moving average calculation where I will need some lines to be constructed like this:

```
var1_ma_past_1=mean(var1, lag1(var1), lag2(var1), lag3(var1), lag4(var1), lag5(var1));
var1_ma_past_2=mean(lag1(var1), lag2(var1), lag3(var1), lag4(var1), lag5(var1), lag6(var1));
var1_ma_past_3=mean(lag2(var1), lag3(var1), lag4(var1), lag5(var1), lag6(var1), lag7(var1));
[...]
var2_ma_past_1=mean(var2, lag1(var2), lag2(var2), lag3(var2), lag4(var2), lag5(var2));
```

my sample program is

```
%macro test ;
    %do i = 1 %to 5;
    %let ln&i = ;
        %do j = 1 %to 5;
            %let dml = %str(,);
            %let pos = %str(lag&i(var&j));
            %let ln&j = %sysfunc(catx(&dml, &&ln&j, &pos));
        %end;
    %end;
    /* example output */
    %put &ln1;
%mend test;
%test
```

`&j` start and end values are planned to be replaced with parameters though.

the output is desired for `&ln1`

```
lag1(var1),lag2(var1),lag3(var1),lag4(var1),lag5(var1)
```

but for `&ln2` `&ln3` etc it's not (`lag1(varn)` is missing)

```
lag2(var4),lag3(var4),lag4(var4),lag5(var4)
lag2(var3),lag3(var3),lag4(var3),lag5(var3)
```

Besides, I got flooding log output saying `ERROR: Required operator not found in expression:` which is because of the parentheses inside of `cats()`, which is inside of `%sysfunc()`, an example macro to replicate this is

```
%macro test2;
    %let x=meow;
    %put %sysfunc(cats(x,lag()));
%mend;
%test2
```

I tried to mask the parentheses with `%str`, `%superq`, `%bquote` but none worked.

I'd like to learn

1. the reason for incorrect output for `&ln2`, `&ln3` and so on
2. the reason for `ERROR: Required operator not found in expression:` and how to fix it (or a workaround, or even to suppress the error if it's not critical)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have SAS ETS licensed? If so, PROC EXPAND can do a lot of these in an easier fashion. You can check your licenses using `proc product_status;run;`

Comment: @Reeza I had the concern that `PROC EXPAND` will also include missing values for moving average value calculation, which I don't want. I also had a feeling that each `PROC EXPAND` will output a dataset, in that case the efficiency is drastically lower, although I haven't actually verified it personally.

Comment: Neither of those concerns are correct. You can do multiple calculations in single call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There is no need to use CAT...() functions in macro code.**

In macro code to concatenate values you just expand them next to each other.
Also it looks like your logic is mixing up the I and J counters.

```
%macro test ;
%do i = 1 %to 5;
  %let list = ;
  %let dlm = ;
  %do j = 1 %to 5;
    %let list = &list.&dlm.lag&j(var&i) ;
    %let dlm = ,;
  %end;
  %put &=i &=list;
%end;
%mend test;
%test
```

Results:

```
I=1 LIST=lag1(var1),lag2(var1),lag3(var1),lag4(var1),lag5(var1)
I=2 LIST=lag1(var2),lag2(var2),lag3(var2),lag4(var2),lag5(var2)
I=3 LIST=lag1(var3),lag2(var3),lag3(var3),lag4(var3),lag5(var3)
I=4 LIST=lag1(var4),lag2(var4),lag3(var4),lag4(var4),lag5(var4)
I=5 LIST=lag1(var5),lag2(var5),lag3(var5),lag4(var5),lag5(var5)
```

For your actual problem you might want to create a macro that only returns the comma delimited list as the result of the macro call.

```
%macro lags(varname,first,last);
%local lag dlm;
%do lag= &first %to &last ;
  %if (&lag > 0) %then %*;&dlm.lag&lag(&varname);
  %else %*;&dlm.&varname;
  %let dlm=,;
%end;
%mend lags;

%put var1_ma_past_1=mean(%lags(var1,0,5));
%put var1_ma_past_2=mean(%lags(var1,1,6));
%put var1_ma_past_3=mean(%lags(var1,2,7));
%put var2_ma_past_1=mean(%lags(var2,0,5));
```

**Why you are getting those error messages:**

The `%sysfunc()` macro function needs to try to figure out whether each argument is character or numeric for a function like `CATX()` that can operate on either type of input.  That is why the `()` in the argument values is confusing it since it looks like you are trying to pass a numeric expression.

```
18    %put %sysfunc(catx(|,a(b),b));
ERROR: Required operator not found in expression: a(b)
a(b)|B
19    %put %sysfunc(catx(|,(1+2),b));
3|B
```

You could force in quotes around the values and then remove them later (if your values don't actually contain quotes).

```
%let left=A(b);
%let right=b;
%let intermediate=%sysfunc(catx(|,"&left","&right"));
%let want=%sysfunc(compress(&intermediate,%str(%"));
%put &=want;
```

Comment: Would you please clarify the use of `%*;`? It seems to have eliminated blanks but the [official documentation for `%&;`](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/mcrolref/62978/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n17rxjs5x93mghn1mdxesvg78drx.htm) doesn't explain how it works.

Comment: The `%*;` is just a really short comment. That is a macro comment. As opposed to a block comment, `/**/`, or a statement comment, `*;`.  What it does is eliminate the white space in front of the text that the macro is generating.

Comment: Wow,  I didn't know that `%*;` actually had a functional use.  I always thought it was just the worst option of the various ways to comment...

Comment: You can use macro comments in macro definitions and they will not print when MPRINT option is on while normal statement style comments will print..  So you can use macro comments to help the coder understand the code andd  use normal statement style comments to help the user understand the log.